# Troubleshoot GCE firewall rules. Does this mean iptables is off? The rules look blank

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall, iptables

I read in other threads that gce firewall rules can fail because iptables is still running on the instance.  I don't admin iptables.  Does the following mean it's not blocking anything?

```
arian@instance-1:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports mdns
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 4000
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: also my gce instance isn't running iptables as a service so all the docs about chkconfig off, service iptables stop don't work.

Comment: this mean iptables blocking most ports but just accept port `mdns` (multicast dns) and `4000` its a well known port.

Comment: I got my iptables cleared with the following commands. Also I learned the hard way that tags on google firewall mean the vm instances the rules should apply to. So after much trial/error I got some ports opened up!! woohoo!!   sudo  iptables -F
sudo  iptables -X
sudo  iptables -t nat -F
sudo  iptables -t nat -X
sudo  iptables -t mangle -F
sudo  iptables -t mangle -X
sudo  iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo  iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo  iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

Comment: @auth private: your statement is incorrect because the default policy on the INPUT chain is ACCEPT.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen  so what about implicit deny like any Access list ? .

Comment: @auth private: There is no such thing. From the iptables documentation: "If the end of a built-in chain is reached or a rule in a built-in chain with target RETURN is matched, the target specified by the chain policy determines the fate of the packet." From the output of the `iptables -L` command provided by the OP, you can see that the policy of the INPUT chain is ACCEPT, i.e. packets are accepted if no rule matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it took to completely turn off iptables on GCE instance.

```
sudo    iptables -F
sudo    iptables -X
sudo    iptables -t nat -F
sudo    iptables -t nat -X
sudo    iptables -t mangle -F
sudo    iptables -t mangle -X
sudo    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Comment: but notice don't forget to save this rules because after restarting ur server all these rules will be restored !